# ReactNative CLI getting error when using React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I generated my project using native cli and I'm using "react-native": "0.67.3" and when I run npx react-native run-android everything is ok and it runs on my android studio emulator and I can write my code.

When I install "npm install @react-navigation/native" to use react navigation, it still works and there is no problem.

But in the second step based on react navigation docs, I need to install react navigation dependencies which are "npm install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context"

As soon as I install them, my code wont run and I encounter this fat error:

```
> Configure project :react-native-safe-area-context
Subproject ':react-native-safe-area-context' has location 'C:\Users\Moe\Desktop\covid\covid\node_modules\react-native-safe-area-context\android' which is outside of the project root. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/upgrading_version_7.html#deprecated_flat_project_structure

> Configure project :react-native-screens
Subproject ':react-native-screens' has location 'C:\Users\Moe\Desktop\covid\covid\node_modules\react-native-screens\android' which is outside of the project root. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/upgrading_version_7.html#deprecated_flat_project_structure
Adding a Configuration as a dependency is a confusing behavior which isn't recommended. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. If you're interested in inheriting the dependencies from the Configuration you are adding, you should use Configuration#extendsFrom instead. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration:extendsFrom(org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration[]) for more details.
    > Task :app:mergeDebugAssets FAILED
    11 actionable tasks: 11 executed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/C:/Users/Moe/Desktop/covid/covid/node_modules/react-native/android/androidx/coordinatorlayout/coordinatorlayout/1.1.0/coordinatorlayout-1.1.0.pom
       - file:/C:/Users/Moe/Desktop/covid/covid/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/androidx/coordinatorlayout/coordinatorlayout/1.1.0/coordinatorlayout-1.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/coordinatorlayout/coordinatorlayout/1.1.0/coordinatorlayout-1.1.0.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/coordinatorlayout/coordinatorlayout/1.1.0/coordinatorlayout-1.1.0.pom
       - https://www.jitpack.io/androidx/coordinatorlayout/coordinatorlayout/1.1.0/coordinatorlayout-1.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-screens
   > Could not find com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/C:/Users/Moe/Desktop/covid/covid/node_modules/react-native/android/com/google/android/material/material/1.1.0/material-1.1.0.pom
       - file:/C:/Users/Moe/Desktop/covid/covid/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/google/android/material/material/1.1.0/material-1.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/android/material/material/1.1.0/material-1.1.0.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/material/material/1.1.0/material-1.1.0.pom
       - https://www.jitpack.io/com/google/android/material/material/1.1.0/material-1.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-screens
   > Could not find androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/C:/Users/Moe/Desktop/covid/covid/node_modules/react-native/android/androidx/core/core-ktx/1.5.0/core-ktx-1.5.0.pom
       - file:/C:/Users/Moe/Desktop/covid/covid/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/androidx/core/core-ktx/1.5.0/core-ktx-1.5.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/core/core-ktx/1.5.0/core-ktx-1.5.0.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/core/core-ktx/1.5.0/core-ktx-1.5.0.pom
       - https://www.jitpack.io/androidx/core/core-ktx/1.5.0/core-ktx-1.5.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-screens

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/C:/Users/Moe/Desktop/covid/covid/node_modules/react-native/android/androidx/coordinatorlayout/coordinatorlayout/1.1.0/coordinatorlayout-1.1.0.pom
       - file:/C:/Users/Moe/Desktop/covid/covid/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/androidx/coordinatorlayout/coordinatorlayout/1.1.0/coordinatorlayout-1.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/coordinatorlayout/coordinatorlayout/1.1.0/coordinatorlayout-1.1.0.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/coordinatorlayout/coordinatorlayout/1.1.0/coordinatorlayout-1.1.0.pom
       - https://www.jitpack.io/androidx/coordinatorlayout/coordinatorlayout/1.1.0/coordinatorlayout-1.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-screens
   > Could not find com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/C:/Users/Moe/Desktop/covid/covid/node_modules/react-native/android/com/google/android/material/material/1.1.0/material-1.1.0.pom
       - file:/C:/Users/Moe/Desktop/covid/covid/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/google/android/material/material/1.1.0/material-1.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/android/material/material/1.1.0/material-1.1.0.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/material/material/1.1.0/material-1.1.0.pom
       - https://www.jitpack.io/com/google/android/material/material/1.1.0/material-1.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-screens
   > Could not find androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/C:/Users/Moe/Desktop/covid/covid/node_modules/react-native/android/androidx/core/core-ktx/1.5.0/core-ktx-1.5.0.pom
       - file:/C:/Users/Moe/Desktop/covid/covid/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/androidx/core/core-ktx/1.5.0/core-ktx-1.5.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/core/core-ktx/1.5.0/core-ktx-1.5.0.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/core/core-ktx/1.5.0/core-ktx-1.5.0.pom
       - https://www.jitpack.io/androidx/core/core-ktx/1.5.0/core-ktx-1.5.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-screens

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s

    at makeError (C:\Users\Moe\Desktop\covid\covid\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\Moe\Desktop\covid\covid\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\Moe\Desktop\covid\covid\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)        
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\Moe\Desktop\covid\covid\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Comment: Try to install `react-native-safe-area-context@3.x.x` and `react-native-screens@3.11.0` because the newer versions are supporting the new Fabric architecture and it may cause some error. Btw when you use `react-native-screens` you need to install `react-navigation/native-stack`.

Comment: @DánielBoros nothing changed, I downgraded to version 3.11 but still get the same error. it fixes when I uninstall the react-native-screen

Comment: I think you are working with react-navigation lower version like 3 or 4